# Adding Category Path in Django Blog

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I am adding a blog to my site and so far everything has been successful. Per the code snippets below, I have a slug field that dynamically creates the url and a tag system.  I am not looking for anything super crazy since the blogs are specifically being used for search engine marketing, but I am missing one important thing that I need help with.

Currently when I create a new blog the path is www.mysite.com/blog/this-is-the-title-slug but what I really need to do is have the ability to create add a category from the admin dashboard that would then insert into the url like so www.mysite.com/blog/mycategory/this-is-the-title-slug.

**Here is some of my code:**

**My Urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views, feed

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name="feed"), name='post_edit'),
]
```

**My Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField


class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)


class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = MarkdownField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

**Screenshot Pointing Out location of Category Insert**

[image]

Thank you for your help.  Happy New Year!!

Comment: Have you tried anything to insert a category?

Comment: I did try to insert a model name with the same pattern as the slug, but was met with an error. The slug thing was easy to figure out but I am still a little lost on creating dynamic url's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a model for category first, something simple like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And add the category to your Entry model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ... < the rest of your model> 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Now if you want to filter by category add this to your urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<category>[^\.]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', 'yourview', name='post_detail'),
```

Remember to modify your view to accept category as parameter and filter the entries with this category.

Comment: Brilliantly Simple - Thank you!! And just to add to your response for others to benefit, my view link becomes <h2><a href="{% url "post_detail" category=object.category slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>